# NoSQL for multi-site archival logging with full-text search

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, cassandra, couchbase, nosql

I'm looking at building a somewhat complex log handling system to replace an old ad-hoc setup and could use a bit of advice. I'm pretty familiar with SQL databases and networking, but am very new to NoSQL stores, which seem to be the key to solving this mess. Note that we have a very good team, but a limited licensing budget, so free/open-source options are vastly preferred. (That said, availability of support if something goes pear-shaped would be nice.)

Requirements:

- Archive (test) logs generated in the several GB/day range at multiple sites around the world.
- Provide full text search of those logs at each site fairly instantaneous for debugging purposes.
- Push that archived data back to a central location (though a replica at each site would be absolutely okay).
- Provide for analytics of that data back at the central location.

Constraints:

- The sites have fairly crap Internet connections for the moment (high latency and fairly low bandwidth). Much of the data is generated during the day and a good portion of the sync would have to lag behind and finish overnight each day.
- Sites MUST be able to function if the WAN goes completely off-line.

Extras

- The log data is (as usual) highly compressible. Any solution that compresses data transacting from node to node across the WAN is preferred.
- Many log files are related to each other in multi-level hierarchies, and that relationship is very important and must be maintained!
- Sites will generally not modify the same data or modify it again once stored. This is all archival for the most part.
- We can either stream as the logs are generated or push blocks of logs. Streaming is preferred, as it would simplify things considerably.

Options I'm aware of:

- Local MySQL and folder structure for logging and local configuration management.

  - This is what we have now and it's running, but not a long-term solution by any means.
- Elasticsearch

  - I've read that [ElasticSearch would probably be really good for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525725/which-nosql-database-should-i-use-for-logging), though from what I understand that doesn't support multi-site.
- Cassandra

  - This seems to have built-in multi-site support, but I'm not exactly familiar with the data-model. Is this a good choice for something like this, or will I hate myself if I give it a try?
- CouchDB

  - This is a document store that seems(?) like a good match for log data, but again doesn't appear to have multi-site support.
- Apache Kafka

  - I read up on this, but I haven't quite wrapped my head around it yet...

Questions:

- Do any of these actually let you stream-append logs or are they best suited to dumping completed files in?
- Is there a solution I'm missing that might be better?
- Any recommendations on multi-site with some of the options that don't support multi-site by themselves?

Interesting links:

- https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying
- http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/07/deploying-apache-kafka-a-practical-faq/
- https://www.elastic.co/blog/scaling_elasticsearch_across_data_centers_with_kafka
- https://kafka.apache.org/08/ops.html
- https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index

Comment: I don't understand why do you need multi-site elasticsearch? There's nice and ready and well-tested solution es/logstash/kibana (so called ELK stack), where you can gather logs from any sites to single location and then index them on elasticsearch cluster, where the data is available for heavy analysis and processing

Comment: That looks like an interesting way to go, but I still need a local ability to search due to the unreliability of WAN links. I'm going to take a deeper look at this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I may be a bit biased, since Couchbase is my employer, but this sounds like the kind of problem that [XDCR (Cross Datacenter Replication)](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/xdcr/xdcr-intro.html) was made to solve.

You could stand up a cluster on multiple geographical sites (Couchbase calls these "datacenters") and then XDCR would automatically replicate (bidirectionally) the data between sites. If I understand your requirements correctly, this sounds like just what you need.

Comment: Ah! I had missed that in the documentation! And it looks like it has unidirectional replication support too, which is even better. (Means most of the datacenters can have relatively small data pools.)