# How to replace JSON escaping characters in dbt

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery, dbt

I have JSON data like this:

`{"payload":"{\"custom\":{\"a\":{\"hs.dl\":\"hs:\\/\\/categories\\/Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9NZW51SXRlbS81NDM2Nzk0NDczODI=\",\"hs.image\":\"https:\\/\\/cms-highstreetapp.imgix.net\\/denham\\/2023\\/08\\/0657f839-0045-49b0-ba89-fbde3c74f519\\/montage20230818-1-kzy7bm.jpg\",\"hs.body\":\"Reworked in the colours of the season.\",\"hs.video_720\":null,\"hs.thumbnail\":\"https:\\/\\/cms-highstreetapp.imgix.net\\/denham\\/2023\\/08\\/0657f839-0045-49b0-ba89-fbde3c74f519\\/montage20230818-1-kzy7bm.jpg\",\"hs.title\":\"Free Move Chinos\",\"hs.video_480\":null,\"hs.id\":\"HS_STUDIO-91428\"},\"i\":\"31d443e3-1874-4deb-b475-ac10c850451d\"},\"aps\":{\"mutable-content\":1,\"alert\":\"Free Move Chinos - Reworked in the colours of the season.\",\"category\":\"category\",\"sound\":\"default\"}}"}`

Currently, I am replacing escaping characters this way:

`REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(value, 'hs.', ''), '\\"', '"'), '"{', "{"), '}"', "}"), '\\/', "/"), '\\n', ' ') AS value`

Just wondering is there any better way to do it in dbt and big query?

EDIT:
I created a function to replace JSON escaping characters, but my whole code gets red color due to characters like `"` any help would be appreciate

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION customReplace(value STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try {
    value = value.replace(/hs\./g, '')
                 .replace(/\\"/g, '"')
                 .replace(/"\{/g, '{')
                 .replace(/\}"/g, '}')
                 .replace(/\\\//g, '/')
                 .replace(/\\n/g, ' ');
    return value;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
""";
```

Comment: What's the point of this?  You have a JSON document nested inside a JSON document.  The right thing to do is to use a programming language to JSON-decode the whole structure.  Then the "payload" item will be proper JSON.

Comment: Can you help me in JS way? I don't know how to do it @TimRoberts

Comment: How are you requesting and receiving this data?  Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: @TimRoberts Would you please take a look at my JS script?
The problem is it doesn't correctly recognize the `"` characters and that made the whole class red.

Comment: What is the expected result? Why do you want to remove special characters? What do you plan to do with the "corrected" string?

Answer (score 1):

> How to replace JSON escaping characters

Consider below approach

```
regexp_replace(text, r'(\\)(.)', r'\2')
```

You can test it with below example

```
with your_table as (
  select '{"payload":"{\"custom\":{\"a\":{\"hs.dl\":\"hs:\\/\\/categories\\/Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9NZW51SXRlbS81NDM2Nzk0NDczODI=\",\"hs.image\":\"https:\\/\\/cms-highstreetapp.imgix.net\\/denham\\/2023\\/08\\/0657f839-0045-49b0-ba89-fbde3c74f519\\/montage20230818-1-kzy7bm.jpg\",\"hs.body\":\"Reworked in the colours of the season.\",\"hs.video_720\":null,\"hs.thumbnail\":\"https:\\/\\/cms-highstreetapp.imgix.net\\/denham\\/2023\\/08\\/0657f839-0045-49b0-ba89-fbde3c74f519\\/montage20230818-1-kzy7bm.jpg\",\"hs.title\":\"Free Move Chinos\",\"hs.video_480\":null,\"hs.id\":\"HS_STUDIO-91428\"},\"i\":\"31d443e3-1874-4deb-b475-ac10c850451d\"},\"aps\":{\"mutable-content\":1,\"alert\":\"Free Move Chinos - Reworked in the colours of the season.\",\"category\":\"category\",\"sound\":\"default\"}}"}' as text
)
select text
from your_table union all
select regexp_replace(text, r'(\\)(.)', r'\2')
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

First row  - original unescaped JSON and second row with resulted escaped JSON

Answer (score 0):

After hours of working with JavaScript, I finally found the right method to replace special characters:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION fix_JSON_Formatting(value STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try {
    value = value.replace(/hs\\./g, '')
                 .replace(/\\\\n/g, ' ')
                 .replace(/\\\\\\//g, '/')
                 .replace(/}\\\"/g, '}')
                 .replace(/\\\"{/g, '{')
                 .replace(/\\\\"/g, '"');
    return value;
  } catch(e) {
    return null;
  }
""";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes dbt is good tool, but it may not be the right tool for this particular operation and sanitization of data.

```
import json
input_json = '{"payload":"{\\"custom\\":{\\"a\\":{\\"hs.dl\\":\\"hs:\\\\/\\\\/categories\\\\/Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9NZW51SXRlbS81NDM2Nzk0NDczODI=\\",\\"hs.image\\":\\"https:\\\\/\\\\/cms-highstreetapp.imgix.net\\\\/denham\\\\/2023\\\\/08\\\\/0657f839-0045-49b0-ba89-fbde3c74f519\\\\/montage20230818-1-kzy7bm.jpg\\",\\"hs.body\\":\\"Reworked in the colours of the season.\\",\\"hs.video_720\\":null,\\"hs.thumbnail\\":\\"https:\\\\/\\\\/cms-highstreetapp.imgix.net\\\\/denham\\\\/2023\\\\/08\\\\/0657f839-0045-49b0-ba89-fbde3c74f519\\\\/montage20230818-1-kzy7bm.jpg\\",\\"hs.title\\":\\"Free Move Chinos\\",\\"hs.video_480\\":null,\\"hs.id\\":\\"HS_STUDIO-91428\\"},\\"i\\":\\"31d443e3-1874-4deb-b475-ac10c850451d\\"},\\"aps\\":{\\"mutable-content\\":1,\\"alert\\":\\"Free Move Chinos - Reworked in the colours of the season.\\",\\"category\\":\\"category\\",\\"sound\\":\\"default\\"}}"}'
prefinal = json.loads(input_json)
final =  {k: json.loads(v) for k, v in prefinal.items()}
print(final)
```

### Output :

```
{'payload': {'custom': {'a': {'hs.dl': 'hs://categories/Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9NZW51SXRlbS81NDM2Nzk0NDczODI=', 'hs.image': 'https://cms-highstreetapp.imgix.net/denham/2023/08/0657f839-0045-49b0-ba89-fbde3c74f519/montage20230818-1-kzy7bm.jpg', 'hs.body': 'Reworked in the colours of the season.', 'hs.video_720': None, 'hs.thumbnail': 'https://cms-highstreetapp.imgix.net/denham/2023/08/0657f839-0045-49b0-ba89-fbde3c74f519/montage20230818-1-kzy7bm.jpg', 'hs.title': 'Free Move Chinos', 'hs.video_480': None, 'hs.id': 'HS_STUDIO-91428'}, 'i': '31d443e3-1874-4deb-b475-ac10c850451d'}, 'aps': {'mutable-content': 1, 'alert': 'Free Move Chinos - Reworked in the colours of the season.', 'category': 'category', 'sound': 'default'}}}
```

one more follow up question, if you are implementing some form of logging, is mysql good or NoSQL (mongodb, or [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525725/which-nosql-database-should-i-use-for-logging) ) good?

the above python code can be wrapped in sql connector this to perform a large scale map-reduce operation to process data at later stage.

what  i intend to quote is,

> one must not fight with language specifics, if there seems no
> obvious-simple way to implement it, sometimes changing tool can save
> us from being called a fool
>
> > - [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)